# Custom Collection Attribute for xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

When using xUnit's [`Collection Fixture`](https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture) feature, a test class must be decorates like this:

```cs
[Collection("MyCollection")]
public class MyTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MyTest() {//...}
}
```

Instead I'd like to introduce a custom attribute `MyCollection` so that I can write:

```cs
[MyCollection]
public class MyTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void MyTest() {//...}
}
```

I thought to derive from [`CollectionAttribute`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.core/CollectionAttribute.cs), but it is marked as `sealed`.

Is there any way to accomplish that using xUnit?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is your use case?

Comment: Because it is tedious to write, easy to forget and an implementation detail of xUnit and not every developer is used to that.

Comment: I think `MyCollection` does have the same problems.

Comment: Introducing a project wide constant for `MyCollection` might reduce the error-proneness, but the above mentioned problems remain.

Comment: That's how I solved it at the moment. I think `[MyCollection]` is easier, but I agree that this is a personal favor. However, I'd like to know whether there is another way.

Comment: Maybe decorator pattern can help here. The `MyCollection` can inherit from `Attribute` and have a `CollectionAttribute` private field, which is initialized with a proper name inside the `MyCollection`'s ctor.

Comment: That was a good idea! Unfortunately, it fails with `Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException The following constructor parameters did not have matching fixture data: MyFixture fixture   Exception doesn't have a stacktrace`

Comment: Did you use the same name here and in the `CollectionDefinition`?

Comment: _it is tedious to write_ - use [code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2019). Create your own snippet that will create a class template with the necessary attributes, etc.

Comment: @PeterCsala Yes, I've used the same name.